# How to compare strings using textview and buttons

Tags: java, android, string, if-statement

I am new to Java and having some difficulty comparing two strings inside a textView. Basically when a user clicks the fillfive button I want the method to set the text to whatever argument is relevant.

For example the default string is "0" so when the user clicks the fillfive button if the string is "0" then it will set the string to "5" else if the string is already "5" it will set the string back to "0".

Any pointers in the right direction would be most welcome, thanks.

Currently in the code below this does not work because I only seem to ever get 0 so I'm guessing for some reason it's not checking the if statement properly.

```
public void fillfive(View v) {
    if (v.toString().equals("0")){
        TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_fivecup);
        view.setText("5");
    }
    else{
        TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_fivecup);
        view.setText("0");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `v.toString()`, you're not actually getting any user input. You need to replace the View parameter with a TextView

```
public void fillfive(View v) {
    TextView textViewA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.the_text_view_you_want_to_check);
    TextView textViewB = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_fivecup);     

    if (textViewA.getText().toString().equals("0")){
        textViewB.setText("5");
    }
    else{
        textViewB.setText("0");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. However this throws the error "Could not find a method fillfive(View) in the activity class or onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'btn_fillfive"

My XML contains android:onClick="fillfive"/>

Shouldn't this work

Comment: Here you go, try this edit. You just need to get a reference to the TextView you wish to check *(just change the id attribute to the correct id :)  )*